# Finding PDF from MGF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The random variable, $X$, has a moment generating function equal to: $M_X(t)= \frac{1}{ (1 − 2t)^3 }$.
Identify the probability density function of $X$.

Answer (score 4):

This is the MGF for the gamma distribution.

$X \sim \Gamma(3,2)$

In general you can show this by converting the MGF to the characteristic function $\Psi_X(\omega)$, i.e. replacing $t$ by $j\omega$, and then use the inverse fourier transform to get the pdf.

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Psi_X(\omega) e^{-j\omega x} d\omega$$

But if you are able to identify the pdf to which the MGF belong you can instead take the easier route and show it by calculating the MGF for the particular pdf.

Answer (score 1):

$$
X \sim \Gamma(k, \theta) \equiv \textrm{Gamma}(k, \theta) 
$$
has probability density function (using the shape-scale parametrization)

$$f(x;k,\theta) = \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)} \quad \text{ for } x > 0 \text{ and } k, \theta > 0$$
and $Γ(k)$ is the gamma function evaluated at $k$.

The mgf is then $$
M(t)=(1 - \theta t)^{-k} $$
for $t < \frac{1}{\theta}$.

> So your variable is 
>   $$
> X \sim \Gamma(3, 2) \equiv \textrm{Gamma}(3, 2) 
> $$

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use the MGF to find the mean and variance? I would just compute those, look for a named distribution that matches, and compute the MGF of that distribution to make sure it's the same. Or did you want a first principles approach to computing the pdf? This is the MGF of a well known distribution.